# Simple bash script if function

Tags: bash

I want to make a bash script that will `ls` the catalog and if it finds file *test* it will launch mplayer, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, one option would be to use `find`:

```
find /path/to/catalog -type f -exec mplayer {} +
```

This searches the catalog directory for any files and builds a command using the results (for example if `file1` and `file2` were found, the command executed would be `mplayer file1 file2`). If no files are found, no command will be executed.